# problem connecting internet through usb modem (micromax)

Tags: 12.04, usb, modem

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04. But I cannot connect to Internet via my USB modem. I created the wireless broadband configuration, but it is not shown in the network menu. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: is the device detected by ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem too. if your usb modem doesnt not detect as usb mass storage,then try this. open terminal type **lsusb**

for example:
$ lsusb

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1c9e:9605 OMEGA TECHNOLOGY

Note down the id of your device i.e from above example 1c9e:9605

and in terminal type **sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x1c9e product=0x9605**

it will ask for user passwd if required.
then wait for some minutes

check the network manager applet if detect it will show the **new mobilebroadband gsm** or cdma,then click the new mobilebroadband. if not detected try to remove modem and connect it

type same cmd **sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x1c9e product=0x9605**

and wait for some minutes. and check network manager
and i think you have to do this every time you reboot the system, till ubuntu team find solution for this.